# Infinite loop in alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton iOS5

Tags: ios5, ios6, uialertview

I'm trying to change the first letter of the user input to the uppercase in the method alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton. Everything works as expected in the iOS 6 but in iOS 5 it seems I get the infinite loop(when I set the text field of the alert view programmatically it calls the method alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton recursively )
Here it is the code:

```
- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:(UIAlertView *)alertView{
    NSString *inputText = [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text];
    if(inputText.length==0)return NO;

    unichar firstChar=[[inputText capitalizedString] characterAtIndex:0];
    NSString *capitalizedLetter= [NSString stringWithCharacters:&firstChar length:1];
    NSString *str=[inputText stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:NSMakeRange(0, 1) withString:capitalizedLetter];

   [[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] setText:str];// setText calls again alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton
    return YES;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`- (BOOL)alertViewShouldEnableFirstOtherButton:` is for the alertView to ask its delegate whether the first (non-cancel) button should be enabled or not. 
The alertView is free to call this method at any time (for instance it might call it when its textfields are changed), to get a YES/NO answer from the delegate. Therefore, you should not implement side effects here.

I would recommend using something like `[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0].delegate = self` and use one of the textField delegate methods (for instance `– textFieldDidBeginEditing:`) to modify the string.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I used the `shouldChangeCharactersInRange` method of `UITextField` to capitalize the first letter of the inserted string.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSLog(@"range: %@ string: %@", NSStringFromRange(range), string);
    if ([string isEqualToString:@""]) {// detect when the user removes symbol
        if ([textField.text length] > 0)textField.text = [textField.text substringToIndex:[textField.text length] - 1];//remove last character from the textfield 
    }
    if (range.location==0) {//capitalize first letter
        NSString *upperString = [[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string] uppercaseString];
        textField.text = upperString;
    }else {
        textField.text=[textField.text stringByAppendingString:string];
    }
    return NO;
}
```